# What are the hidden portraits in Heroes of the Storm?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

There seem to be some hidden portraits in Heroes of the Storm, for example the alpha portrait, or the level 40 beta portrait.

Does the level 40 alpha portrait also exist? What are all the hidden portraits and can you/how do you acquire them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are currently twelve hidden portraits in the game. Some of them you are no longer able to obtain:

**Alpha Player**

[image: Alpha Player Portrait]

Awarded for playing during the technical alpha.

**Alpha Hero**

[image: Alpha Hero Portrait]

Awarded for reaching player level 40 during the technical alpha.

**Beta Player**

[image: Beta Player Portrait]

Awarded for playing during the beta.

**Beta Hero**

[image: Beta Hero Portrait]

Awarded for reaching player level 40 during beta.

**Lunar Festival**

[image: Lunar Festival Portrait]

Awarded for playing 10 games during the Lunar Festival holiday.

**BlizzCon 2014**

[image: BlizzCon 2014 Portrait]

Awarded for attending BlizzCon 2014 (or purchasing the virtual ticket).

**Wonder Billie**

[image: Wonder Billie Portrait]

Awarded for making a real money purchase during alpha or beta.  (Also grants the Wonder Billie mount.)

**Billie the Kid**

[image: Billie the Kid Portrait]

Awarded for making a real money purchase after the game was released.  (Also grants the Billie the Kid mount.)

**Heroes of the Dorm**

[image: Heroes of the Dorm Fantasy Bracket Portrait]

Awarded for submitting a fantasy bracket prediction for the [Heroes of the Dorm](https://heroesofthedorm.com) tournament.

**Launch Week**

[image: Launch Week Portrait]

Awarded for logging in during the first week of release (June 2, 2015 - June 9, 2015).

**Facebook**

[image: Facebook Portrait]

Reward for the Heroes Facebook page receiving one million likes.  Awarded for logging in between June 30, 2015 and the release of the next major patch.

**Golden Tiger**

[image]

Rewarded when redeeming the Golden Tiger mount key found in the Heroes of the Storm Starter Pack.

Comment: You miss Dunk'modan portrait bro, from the event Heroes of the Dorm :)

Comment: Is that the actual name?  Found a pic of it, but haven't seen anyone in-game using it.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a portrait from a TeSPA promotion. TeSPA Chen (Chen wearing a graduation hat with a TeSPA logo in the lower right corner).

[image: TeSPA Chen]