# What does the Billie the Kid mount look like?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

In Heroes of the Storm, there is a promotion starting with launch to give the Billie the Kid mount with any cash purchase.  There would be three different tints (color schemes) for the mount.  What do they look like?

You can read more about this on [battle.net](http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/forum/topic/17905501222).

Note that the portrait that goes with the mount is shown in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/219807/51171).  I'm not talking about the portrait though.  I'm looking for cropped screenshots of the mount selection screen for each tint.  Action shots wouldn't hurt either, but I'd rather have the selection screen.

Remember that Billie the Kid is different from the Wonder Billie mount.  My question is aimed at seeing how different (contrast shots wouldn't hurt).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three Billie the Kid variations: white, brown, and black.

The default is white:

[image: Main White Billie the Kid skin]
[image]
[image]

Here's the brown one:

[image: Brown Billie the Kid skin]

Here's the black one:

[image: Black Billie the Kid skin]

The Wonder Billie mounts use the same model, but have different textures and additional effects:

[image: White Wonder Billie Skin]
[image: Turquoise Wonder Billie skin]
[image: Pink Wonder Billie skin]